# How to prevent some HTTP methods from being exported from my MongoRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-data-rest and I have a MongoRepository like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface MyEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

I would like to allow the GET methods but disable PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE (read only web service).

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource I should be able to do that like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface MyEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public MyEntity save(MyEntity s);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void delete(String id);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void delete(MyEntity t);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work as I can still do PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE requests.

Comment: That should work, can you provide a test case/test project that shows this failing?

Comment: After testing again today, it actually works.

However, I can't find how to restrict the GET method on /myEntities.

Adding the annotation to `List<MyEntity> findAll();` does nothing.

Comment: `MongoRepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` so you need to redeclare and annotate `findAll(Pageable pageable)`.

Comment: Thanks, I made an answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thanks to Oliver, here are the methods to override:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    // Prevents GET /people/:id
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public Person findOne(String id);

    // Prevents GET /people
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    // Prevents POST /people and PATCH /people/:id
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public Person save(Person s);

    // Prevents DELETE /people/:id
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void delete(Person t);

}
```

Comment: can i disable put? i want all new entities to be created through POST

Comment: You might try to annotate `public Person insert(Person entity)` but I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 16):

This is late reply, but if you need to prevent the global http method for a entity, try it.

```
@Configuration
public class DataRestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
         config.getExposureConfiguration()
                .forDomainType(Person.class)
                .withItemExposure(((metdata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST, ... )))
                .withCollectionExposure((metdata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST, ...));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use like this?

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDataRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration restConfig) {
        restConfig.disableDefaultExposure();
    }
}
```